# Remove one folder name among two from the url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a folder called users in the root. Inside the users folder there a are other folders by user names below is the folder structure.

```
example.com/users/mike
```

inside the mike folder there is the index.php
how can I remove the folder name users from the url
 like example.com/mike
These folders under user (eg: mike) is created dynamically.

Below is the htaccess code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+users/(\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

Its removing the folder name but showing page not found error.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're missing the 2nd rule that you need to accomplish this. You need 2 rules. Try this code for the complete rewrite.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+users/(\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /users/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest.

Comment: But now neither http://example.com/users/mike/  or http://example.com/mike/ URLs are opening

Comment: What do you mean they are not opening? What exactly happens? And do you have anything else in your .htaccess file. If so paste it in the question.

Comment: no I dont have anything else in my .htaccess file. Please check this url http://landlordin.com/ , http://landlordin.com/mike/, http://landlordin.com/tony only the landing page is opening. Folder structure is root/users(folder mike and folder tony) mike and tont folder contains only index.php file